# How to test WordPress theme compatibility?

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, compatibility

I was given a WordPress theme package with dozens of themes. There is no readme so I am not sure what versions these were targeted for. Is there are way to test a theme's compatibility with my WordPress install (version 3.2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just put all the themes in the "themes" folder and then 'preview' each one from the appearance menu ?